# How to Export styles as css file in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-cli

I am new in Angular 4 and I want to export my styles as `css` file. 
When I serve or build the project, it creates a `style.bundle.js` file and add css' as html style element. But I want to export as stylesheet file and load it with `link` element.

My Angular-cli.json :

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "ares"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "name":"desktop",
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist/desktop",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "views/desktop"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
        "assets/desktop/css/styles.scss",
        "views/desktop/trader/first/assets/css/theme.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.js",
        "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: What style are you talking about? assets/desktop/css/styles.scss? Or, anything else?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `angular-cli`.  Is it using `webpack`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you running `ng build` or `ng serve` it always creates a bundle like `styles.bundles.js` just for sake of saving some time on the dev build. From another hand, if you do `ng build --prod` it will produce `styles.bundle.css`.

If you want  `styles.bundle.css` to be produced for your dev build then just add `--extract-css` flag e.g `ng serve --extract-css`.

Here is some more details on default `flags` that might be helpful:

[image]

Comment: how can i see css line on chrome dev tools in dev mod :( I only see <style>..</style>

Comment: if you run `ng serve --extract-css` you should be able to see your styles, just go to network tab.