# Export css files in angular 7

Tags: css, angular, angular7

Is there a way that I can export SCSS files of few components in my angular project as assets of my project while creating a production build?

If I can then I would like to export them in CSS format so that I can use them somewhere else.

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46532268/how-to-export-styles-as-css-file-in-angular-4

Comment: that just gives me styles.bundle.css what I need is few of the component's CSS in my assets folder as .css files. For example if I have a component abc and that component uses abc.component.scss file for styling. What I need is in my production build may be inside assets folder or any other folder to get abc.component.scss file as abc.css file.

Comment: or at least if I can get that components style in my angular code in a variable even that will work.

Comment: @PritamKadam check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649471/converts-scss-to-css) without angular. May help.

Comment: I think the only way to achieve this is by creating redundant CSS. Unfortunately.